# Regex - check if exist but don't include it

Tags: regex

Text:

```
Name=Jennifer,Age=29,Height=1.70,Occupation=Actress...
```

Regex:

```
(?<Name>(?:Name=)\w+)?\,?(?<Age>(?:Age=)\d+)?\,?(?<Height>(?:Height=)[\d.]+)?\,?(?<Occupation>(?:Occupation=)\w+)?\,?
```

Result:

```
Full match  `Name=Jennifer,Age=29,Height=1.70,Occupation=Actress`
Group `Name`    `Name=Jennifer`
Group `Age` `Age=29`
Group `Height`  `Height=1.70`
Group `Occupation`  `Occupation=Actress`
```

How to make keys not part of the group, but check if they exist?

Comment: with a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: @Unamata Sanatarai not working.

Comment: Actually it should be lookbehind, not lookahead.

Comment: Parsing key=value lists like this is usually much easier using the language's string splitting functions rather than regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it is a bad idea to use a regex that only consists of optional patterns (because you need to handle empty matches, the patterns only match in a predefined order, and it is not possible to make it work with positive lookaheads since all are optional). **It will make more sense to just use `Name=(\w+)`, `Age=(\d+)` like regexes to extract all the necessary details.**

If you want to follow your path, you may try fixing your pattern by putting the keys outside the capturing groups:

```
(?:Name=(?<Name>\w+))?,?(?:Age=(?<Age>\d+))?,?(?:Height=(?<Height>[\d.]+))?,?(?:Occupation=(?<Occupation>\w+))?,?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/teHmSy/2)

[image]

Comment: I need to check if "Name=" is there. What if I delete "Name=Jennifer", still I need to parse the rest.

Comment: @S.Kablar In that case, use separate small regexes - it will be the best idea. Or wrap all with optional non-capturing groups.